# Loading images from @android/drawable

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am going to use the navigation drawer in my app. I chose the one that Android Studio is giving me. That's how it looks like.

[image: navigation drawer]

I want to change the images and the text next to them. For the images I found this xml file inside the values folder.

**drawable**

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item name="ic_menu_camera" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera</item>
<item name="ic_menu_gallery" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery</item>
<item name="ic_menu_slideshow" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow</item>
<item name="ic_menu_manage" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage</item>
<item name="ic_menu_share" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_share</item>
<item name="ic_menu_send" type="drawable">@android:drawable/ic_menu_send</item>
```

Instead,I want to use images that represent numbers,but I can't find anything in the @android/drawable forder. Also,how do I change the text ie import to players and so on?

Thanks.

Comment: In the drawable menu file you can change the `title` and `icon` attributes for each menu item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make or get your own drawable and reference you package? @android:drawable/* is not going to work for 90% of your use-case in terms of specific drawables.

To find where the text is for your items you should check your values directory and find those strings that are being referenced and replace as necessary.